# Query runs in Access but generates error in C# DataSet

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, xsd, ms-access-2007

I have this query, whoch runs fine when I test it in Access, but I'm running it <strike>from TSQL</strike> in an outside C# program (honestly, I'm still learning the terms so I think TSQL is correct for what I'm doing (It was not)). When I try to store the procedure in a tableadapter in my XSD file I get an error (see below the query). As a result the proper XML schema is not automatically created. While the query still *runs* it also gives an error. I'd like it to run without the error but can't figure out where that error really is. I tried eliminating all the "=" by replacing the IIFs with CASE statements but then I got other errors ( I can post that attempt if it would be helpful)

```
SELECT  IIF(ISNULL(Owners.OwnFirstName), Owners.OwnLastName, 
         Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ' + Owners.OwnLastName) AS [Owner's Name], SUM(iif(UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'N', 1, 0)) 
         AS [Neph units], SUM(iif(UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'F', 1, 0)) AS [Filter units], COUNT(UnitBarcodes.NephStatus) 
         AS [Total Units]
FROM  (Owners INNER JOIN
         ((UnitBarcodes INNER JOIN
         AssembledUnits ON UnitBarcodes.ID = AssembledUnits.CaseID) INNER JOIN
         OwnerUnits ON AssembledUnits.ID = OwnerUnits.AssembledUnitID) ON Owners.ID = OwnerUnits.OwnerID)
GROUP BY IIF(ISNULL(Owners.OwnFirstName), Owners.OwnLastName, 
         Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ' + Owners.OwnLastName)
```

Error message from Query Builder

```
Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.
```

Anyway, thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

This was my previous attempt at replacing the IIFs with CASEs

```
SELECT   (case when ISNULL(Owners.OwnFirstName) then Owners.OwnLastName else (Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ' + Owners.OwnLastName) end) AS [Owner's name],
          SUM(case where UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'N' then  1 else 0 end)) 
          AS [Neph units], SUM( case when UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'F' then 1 else 0 end)) AS [Filter units], COUNT(UnitBarcodes.NephStatus) 
          AS [Total units]
FROM         (Owners inner JOIN
          ((UnitBarcodes inner JOIN
          AssembledUnits ON UnitBarcodes.ID = AssembledUnits.CaseID) INNER JOIN
          OwnerUnits ON AssembledUnits.ID = OwnerUnits.AssembledUnitID) ON Owners.ID = OwnerUnits.OwnerID)
GROUP BY (case when ISNULL(Owners.OwnFirstName) then Owners.OwnLastName else (Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ' + Owners.OwnLastName) end) AS [Owner's name]
```

And the error I get is

```
Error in list of function arguments: 'ISNULL' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: ')' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.
```

**EDIT2:**

So this query works just fine

```
SELECT     IIF(ISNULL(Owners.OwnFirstName), Owners.OwnLastName, 
            Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ' + Owners.OwnLastName) AS [Owner's Name], COUNT(UnitBarcodes.NephStatus) 
            AS [Total units]
FROM         (Owners INNER JOIN
            ((UnitBarcodes INNER JOIN
            AssembledUnits ON UnitBarcodes.ID = AssembledUnits.CaseID) INNER JOIN
            OwnerUnits ON AssembledUnits.ID = OwnerUnits.AssembledUnitID) ON Owners.ID = OwnerUnits.OwnerID)
GROUP BY IIF(ISNULL(Owners.OwnFirstName), Owners.OwnLastName, 
            Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ' + Owners.OwnLastName)
```

But as soon as I add any Sum (be it through CASEs or IIFs) the query generates an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a COALESCE to replace the NULL columns with an empty string and a CASE to replace the IIF in the SUMs.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ','') + Owners.OwnLastName AS [Owner's Name],  
        SUM(CASE WHEN UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Neph units], 
        SUM(CASE WEHN UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Filter units], 
        COUNT(UnitBarcodes.NephStatus) AS [Total Units]
FROM  (Owners INNER JOIN
         ((UnitBarcodes INNER JOIN
         AssembledUnits ON UnitBarcodes.ID = AssembledUnits.CaseID) INNER JOIN
         OwnerUnits ON AssembledUnits.ID = OwnerUnits.AssembledUnitID) ON Owners.ID = OwnerUnits.OwnerID)
GROUP BY COALESCE(Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ','') + Owners.OwnLastName
```

Comment: Why is the query designer wanting to change `COALESCE(Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ','')` to `[COALESCE](Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ', '')` ?

Comment: When I try to run what you have there I get `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM(CASE WHEN UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` then It highlights the `WHEN` in that phrase. (this is when attempted in Access. I also get an error, just di9fferent, in VS `IErrorInfo.Getdescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).`)

Comment: Ok, So if I remove the SUMs and execute the query I get a better error I think. `Undefined function '[COALESCE]' in expression.` I can delete the []s but the designer just puts them back. Any more thoughts?

Comment: @Brad Are you sure you're running this against a DB that uses T-SQL?

Comment: Not positive. As I said in the question the verbiage is still new to me. I added a dataset to my project. It made an XSD file with table adapters and the like. Which is all connecting to Access. I guess I assumed that TSQL represented the go between for what I'm doing and my DB, but am I wrong?

Comment: @Brad No. Access does not use TSQL. I misunderstood and thought you were trying to convert your Access query to run against a TSQL DB.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your IIF statements to CASE statements, IIF is not valid T-SQL syntax.

In response to your comment, that's not how a null check is done in t-sql, here is an example:

```
CASE
     WHEN SomeValue IS NULL THEN
          SomeDefault
     ELSE
          SomeValue 

END
```

Comment: @Maess Let me introduce you to the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) and [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) functions. ;-)

Comment: Hi Joe, I'm aware of COALESCE, however, you need to start with the fundamentals, like CASE and how to do a null check.  Yes there is a function for it, but it's better to start with how it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of syntax-errors.

I formated the last attempt you made and corrected some errors. Hope this works for you.

```
SELECT  case    when Owners.OwnFirstName IS NULL 
                then Owners.OwnLastName 
                else Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ' + Owners.OwnLastName 
        end AS [Owner's name]
        ,SUM(case when UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Neph units]
        ,SUM(case when UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Filter units]
        ,COUNT(UnitBarcodes.NephStatus) AS [Total units]
FROM    Owners 
JOIN    OwnerUnits
    ON  Owners.ID = OwnerUnits.OwnerID
JOIN    AssembledUnits
    ON  AssembledUnits.ID = OwnerUnits.AssembledUnitID
JOIN    UnitBarcodes 
    ON  UnitBarcodes.ID = AssembledUnits.CaseID
GROUP BY 
    case    when Owners.OwnFirstName IS NULL 
            then Owners.OwnLastName 
            else Owners.OwnFirstName + ' ' + Owners.OwnLastName 
    end
```

Comment: I tried this but it still gives errors. I tried to break it down to smaller parts. `SUM(case when UnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Neph units]` and `SELECT     SUM(iif(MicroPEMUnitBarcodes.NephStatus = 'N', 1, 0))  AS [Neph units]
FROM         MicroPEMUnitBarcodes` both return errors HOWEVER the second one after the error will then return my data in the way I want it. (both errors are `syntax errors`)

Comment: Well, I have to surrender this one. It now seems that the question does not regard t-sql. I misunderstood the question just the same way Joe Stefanelli did. I wont be able to help you on this one. Sorry!

Comment: :/ Yeah sorry. Oh well. I will continue to try to work with this. Thanks for the help either way.