# Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized. unable to parse query text. - C# Table Adapter

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

This is a follow-up of a previous requestion.
[Here Is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837386/how-to-select-the-same-field-twice-with-different-conditions-and-display-results/)

**It Was about selecting Value from the same field twice with different conditions and display results in separate fields**

> And Used Following Code In table Adapter - IIF

```
SELECT AttendanceReg.StudentID,AttendanceReg.Studname, AttendanceReg.StudSex,
AttendanceReg.StudCourse,
SUM(IIf( AttendanceReg.AttendStatus = 'Present', 1,0)) AS TotalPresent,
SUM(IIf( AttendanceReg.AttendStatus = 'Absent', 1,0)) AS TotalAbsent, 
DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance) AS MYMONTH

FROM (AttendanceReg
    INNER JOIN LocalTable ON
    AttendanceReg.StudCourse = LocalTable.AttendCourse 
    AND 
    DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance) = LocalTable.AttentMonth)

GROUP BY AttendanceReg.StudentID, AttendanceReg.Studname,
    AttendanceReg.StudSex, AttendanceReg.StudCourse,
    DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance)

ORDER BY DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance) DESC
```

> Also, I Have Tried by Replacing "IIF" With "Switch" Like Below

```
SUM(SWITCH(EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Present',1,
EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Absent', 0)) AS TotalPresent,
SUM(SWITCH(EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Absent',1,
EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Present', 0)) AS TotalAbsent,
```

> Both the Querys Are Working Prefectly While Testing.
>   [image]
>   But this what happening While trying to create table adapter :(

[image]
[image]
 - how to solve this issue?

- Can use any other Query instead of this?

Comment: problem is in your query, can you share query?

Comment: already i have mentioned the query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563231/query-runs-in-access-but-generates-error-in-c-sharp-dataset - See Lot of people had the same issue before..is there any solution.

Comment: Did that solution solved your problem?

Comment: no... can you please tell me your mail id\